# Replacing the media creation date of each file in a folder with last modifictaion date automatically

Tags: file-management, google-photos

I got a folder of about 1000 videos (downloaded from Snapchat). The encoded *media creation date*  (not to confuse with the *file creation date*)  of the videos is incorrect, but the *last modified* time stamp is correct. When the videos are uploaded to google photos, the date of the videos inside of Google Photos is incorrect, do to the wrong *media creation date*.

I want to replace the *media creation date* of each of the files in the folder with the files *last modifictaion date*, automatically using CMD, Powershell or any other program that is capable of this.

Answer (score 1):

I found this very useul program called BulkFileChanger, which is capable of doing what i wanted (and a lot more)

Download link for [BulkFileChanger](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html)

For my specific purpose i used the following settings:

[image: Change file time/attributes settings]

The videos are now sorted correctly in Google Photos